# Ayuda con consulta sql (count) en jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Necesito hacer una consulta con la funcion `count` de `plsql` que me devuelva el numero de filas de una consulta que cumpla unos requisitos para luego hacer un `if`, pero no consigo que me devuelva nada. Este es el trozo de codigo.

```
Class.forName(driver);
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuariobd, clave);

                /*guardando la conexion en la session*/
                session.setAttribute("conexion", con);

                Statement com = con.createStatement();
                        String textoComando = "SELECT count(idTitulacion) NumeroFilas FROM titulacionalumnos where nombre='" + titulo + "' and centroTitulo='" + centroTitulo + "'; ";
                ResultSet resultado = com.executeQuery(textoComando);

                int numFilas=0;
                while (resultado.next()) {
                    numFilas=resultado.getInt("NumeroFilas");
                    out.println("<h1>numero de filas: " + numFilas + "</h1>");
                    if (numFilas == 0) {
                        out.println("<div>No existe este titulo. Se registrara el nuevo titulo</div>");
                    } else {
                        out.println("<div>El titulo es  " + titulo + " " + centroTitulo + "</div>");
                    }

                }
```

La conexion a la base de datos esta bien, y los valores que le paso desde un formulario tambien los recoge bien. Gracias

Comment: Prueba a quitar el `;` dentro de `textoComando`. Y creo que deberías usar un `try... catch` para controlar las posibles excepciones, [como muestra la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html).

Comment: ¿Qué error arroja? ¿A qué te refieres con "no devuelve nada"?

Comment: No me da ningún error, solo que no entra en el while(resultado.next()). El try catch lo tengo puesto, solo en el que no lo he copiado aquí. Gracias

Comment: ya lo he solucionado, al hacer la llamada al servidor MySQL está poniendo otra base de datos, soy retrasado